# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

every now and then this error appears when I launch my script. It doesn't happen all the time, I often only need to run the script again to not get this message anymore.
What could be the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 927, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC9943+2595139]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E5C9F1+2148849]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D543F0+1065968]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D45A97+1006231]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D44AD0+1002192]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D450D8+1003736]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D45068+1003624]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D4B220+1028640]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D462AD+1008301]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D467C5+1009605]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D465AF+1009071]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D45BC6+1006534]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D4542B+1004587]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D452C9+1004233]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D558A0+1071264]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DAB3BB+1422267]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D9B806+1357830]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D76086+1204358]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D76F96+1208214]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0106B232+1658114]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0112312C+2411516]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F5F261+560433]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F5E366+556598]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E6286B+2173035]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E675F8+2192888]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E676E5+2193125]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E711FC+2232828]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76A1FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77007A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77007A4E+238]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check that:

- Selenium is upgraded to the latest available version
- ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser are updated to the latest available version
- Or, if you use Firefox, check that GeckoDriver and Firefox Browser are updated to the latest available version